# Bindings calling order

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

Suppose we have the following QML code:

```js
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    id: win
    width: 800
    height: 600


    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        width: 100
        height: 100
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "orange"
        property bool test: false
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                rect.test = true;
            }
        }
    }

    Item {
        property bool test: rect.test
        onTestChanged: {
            rect.color = "green"
        }
    }
    Item {
        property bool test: rect.test
        onTestChanged: {
            rect.color = "yellow"
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above there are 2 bindings to property `test` of item `rect`. Which is the evaluation order of the bindings, in this case? Most importantly, can I manage it and set a specific order?

Answer (score 3):

The order is undefined. I could have sworn that there was documentation about this at one stage, but now all I can find are small references here and there:

[Positioning with Anchors](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-anchors.html):

> Because the evaluation order of bindings is not defined [...]

[JavaScript Expressions in QML Documents](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-expressions.html):

> If there is more than one onCompleted() handler to execute at startup, they are run sequentially in an undefined order.

Comment: Thanks, @Mitch, that what I've assumed too.So, as I understand, there isn't way to manage it?